# Extrapolate data in an excel file using python script

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas, extrapolation

I have a given dataset of some countries with the following fields:

```
DATE
SOURCE COMPANY 
DESTINATION COMPANY 
QUANTITY
UNITS
```

I have 2 days worth of data and I need to extrapolate the data for a year with dates and quantity values for each company and print the results in excel.

I need 1 row per company `x` delivered to per company `y` for 1 year. The dates can be from 2018 till today and the quantities can have difference of +/- 100.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os 
import datetime 
import random 
import sys 
from datetime import timedelta 

df = pd.read_csv("Location") 
df_1 = df 
for i in range(1,366): 
  for i in range(0,df.shape[0]): 
    df['Quantity'][i] = df['Quantity'][i] + random.randint(-100,100)    
    df['Date'][i] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])[i] + timedelta(days = -1)

df_1 = pd.concat([df_1,df]) 
df_1.to_csv("Extrapolated_data.csv",sep = '')
```

but the time its consuming is unacceptable, how do I make it better

Comment: You want to extrapolate how many units company x from country y sold to company Z 6 months ago using data from the last 2 days?

Comment: @DanielleM. 

I need 1 unit per company x  delivered to per company y for 1 year and yes I have data for 2 days. the dates can be from 2018 till date and the quantities can have difference of +/- 100

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a free code writing service. You still need to write your own code. When you run into specific problems, we can help. Please [edit] your question and post your code. You may want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! I applied a bit of code highlighting but right now your question is not self-explanatory as it lacks details you just mentioned in the comments. Please update your question with more details so more users can help. If you already tried some code, post it as well. I exchanged the word `unit` with `row` as we are talking about an Excel export, if that was wrong, please correct it and add a definition what `unit` is supposed to mean.

Comment: For the future: please edit your question (there is an "edit" link below your question) and include more details like the code you posted in your comment as the formatting will get lost. I did that for you this time. Regarding your code: please have a look at a fixed version of your code in my answer below and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are some issues with the code you posted in your comment to your question that you have to take care of:

1. `sep` in the `df_1.to_csv()` parameter needs to be set to a character i.e. "," or ";" (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html?highlight=to_csv#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)), otherwise simply omit it if you don't want to use another separator then ","
2. There is no `.csv` extension on your source file (which may be perfectly fine)
3. Assigning `df_1 = df` will not only copy the columns/meta-data of the DataFrame, but the DataFrame **including all data**. This will result in a file containing the original data and generated data.

**Updated code**

As I am still new to pandas, I see no way to iterate over only the rows but instead had to iterate rows and columns which results in the below code. My sample file has about 40 rows in total, the result file has ~13.000 rows with a file size of 619 KB. Creation time is 60,007 seconds. Removing the time calculations and randomness from the code reduces the creation time to 54,38 seconds. This isn't super-fast but I wouldn't call this super-slow, either.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os 
import datetime 
import random 
import sys 
from datetime import timedelta 
from timeit import default_timer as timer

df = pd.read_csv("orders.csv") 
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns) 
start = timer()

for d in range(1,366):
  for index, dfc in df.iterrows():

    dfc['Quantity'] = dfc['Quantity'] + random.randint(-100,100)    
    dfc['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['Date']) + timedelta(days = -d)
    df_1 = df_1.append(dfc, ignore_index=True)

  print("Loop ",d)  

end = timer()
print(end - start) 

df_1.to_csv("Extrapolated_data.csv",sep = ',')
```

Comment: the first loop was to generate data for a year, hence the `(1,365)`
the `random.randint(-100,100)` was to randomize and generate a value between +/-100 to give me a random forecast for a year
the `Timedelta(days = -1)` is to generate data for a year in the past from the start date given in the excel file


The end goal was to generate extrapolated data for a year (e.g from 2015 - till date) of any given company while randomizing their quantities between +/-100 for each day (i.e the dates generated from 2015 - till date)

Comment: @OsamaTariq I updated the above code, main problem seems to be index-based access, i.e. `df['Quantity'][i]`. I also see that `.append()` is not as fast as `pd.concat()` but I couldn't find a way to incorporate this into my code.